# Many-to-one relationship using two unique keys

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables which look like thiS:

```
uploads
________
id (primary key)
user_id
file_checksum
```

```
upload_information
---------
upload_info_id (primary key)
file_checksum
metadata1
metdata2
```

The "many to one" relationship I am trying to enforce is this:

- Many uploads can have the same file checksum
- However, the file checksum can only ever point to one `upload_information` record, thus making the unique constraint between `file_checksum` and `upload_info_id` mandatory in the `upload_information` table.

I am wondering how to alter these tables in Postgres in order to achieve this relationship.

```
CREATE TABLE uploads (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  user_id VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  file_checksum VARCHAR NOT NULL,
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE upload_information (
  upload_info_id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  file_checksum VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  file_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  source_file_url VARCHAR NOT NULL,
);
```

Comment: What do you want to happen when two users upload the same content with different file names and source URLs?

Comment: The only part that matters is the MD5 checksum of the contents of the file, the other information comes from internal sources, not user edited.

Comment: [MD5 is broken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security), even for file checksums. May I suggest moving to [SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2)? I would also suggest storing the checksum as an [`bytea`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html), not its hex string representation. It is more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a [unique index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-unique.html) on `file_checksum`.

```
create unique index unique_checksum on upload_information(file_checksum)
```

Comment: then do I need to add a `REFERENCES` statement on the `uploads` `file_checksum`?

Comment: @codeadventurer No, it is not a reference. However, with that unique index there is only one `upload_information` for every `file_checksum`. Instead of storing `uploads.file_checksum` you should store a foreign key `uploads.upload_information_id`. That does take a `references`. That makes the relationship between `uploads` and `upload_information` explicit. Referential integrity now works, and you can do reference checks like `on delete`.